# Role that can set roles but not change its own

Tags: users

In our sites, I have an Admin role (me) and Staff roles.  The Staff role needs to be able to create client user accounts and assign client specific roles to those accounts.  How can I give my staff the permission to set other's roles but not their own?  I don't want them changing themselves to an admin when they want to (and they have).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this with some success in the past:  http://drupal.org/project/role_delegation

I believe I also ended up formatting some of the user profile edit forms to make it simpler for the end user, but I can't quite recall.

Comment: Applied this today and it is exactly what I wanted.  Thanks and a green checkmark for you.

Answer (score 2):

It really sounds like there should be a module that does this ... I'm not aware of 1 offhand.

You could use hook_form_alter on the user account form and simply check the role of the logged in user. If they are `Staff` allow them to set roles to all but the Admin role you've defined. You would simply `unset()` the admin value in the `$options` array for the Roles checkboxes.

For example:

```
function MYMODULE_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;
  if (array_search('Staff', $user->roles)) {
    // Any RIDs you want to remove.
    unset($form['account']['roles']['#options'][3]);
  }
}
```

You would also probably want to add a validator to this form to check that a Staff user does not try to get around this by setting this value for instance via Firefox's Firebug. I leave that exercise to you.

Comment: Good suggestion.  Next time I am in the code I will try this out.  Boundaries are a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want [Administer Users By Role](http://drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole):

> If the user-being-edited has multiple roles, the user-doing-the-editing must have permission to edit ALL of the user-being-edited's roles.

This seems like it would prevent users from administering themselves, if they were given a role they couldn't administer.

Comment: Apparently I am not the only one with this problem.  I am going to try these modules soon.  Thx.

Comment: This might have done the trick too but role_delegation did exactly what I wanted. Thx.